# Angular "ng serve" падает с ошибкой

Tags: angular

Использую "ng serve" для отладки. Через какое-то время, она начинает падать с ошибкой после сохранения файлов. Помогает удаление полностью папки "node_modules" и "package-lock.json", с последующим "npm i". Но этого хватает на день, потом опять падает. Что это может быть?

VSCode
MacBook

Ошибка:

```
node:internal/process/promises:289
        triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
        ^

[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/Users/alex/Desktop/Work/Front/.angular/cache/17.1.2/angular-webpack/6601648d8691d08c2804c968a986632ae965a99e/8.pack'] {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'stat',
  path: '/Users/alex/Desktop/Work/Front/.angular/cache/17.1.2/angular-webpack/6601648d8691d08c2804c968a986632ae965a99e/8.pack'
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77426906/4496422